# Why isn't my python code outputting float?

Tags: python

When I run this it doesn't output the float "Pay".  I tried some things.

```
#h:hours, oth:overtime hours, pr:payrate, otpr:overtime payrate

h = input("Enter hours worked")
float(h)
oth = float(h) - 40.00
pr = 10.00
otpr = (pr * 1.5)

if float(h) > 40:
    Pay = (float(h) * pr) + (oth * otpr)
else: Pay = (float(h) * pr)

print ('Your pay is'), + Pay
```

Comment: You can get the input as a float itself by doing this `float(input(": "))` and the variable Pay should be inside `print()`

Answer (score 2):

in python 3.x 'print' is a function and not a command (what was in python 2.7)

so if you want to print 'Pay':

```
print ('Your pay is ', Pay)
```